# LeetCode: Merge k sorted lists C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, linked-list, mergesort, heap

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/

> Merge k sorted linked lists and return it as one sorted list. Analyze
>   and describe its complexity.
>
> ```
> Example:
>
> Input:
> [
>   1->4->5,
>   1->3->4,
>   2->6
> ]
> Output: 1->1->2->3->4->4->5->6
> ```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Heap;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace LinkedListQuestions
{/// <summary>
/// https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/
/// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class MergeKSortedLists
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void LeetCodeExample()
        {
            ListNode l1 = new ListNode(1);
            l1.next = new ListNode(4);
            l1.next.next = new ListNode(5);

            ListNode l2 = new ListNode(1);
            l2.next = new ListNode(3);
            l2.next.next = new ListNode(4);

            ListNode l3 = new ListNode(2);
            l3.next = new ListNode(6);
            ListNode[] arr = new ListNode[] { l1, l2, l3 };

            ListNode res = MergeKSortedListsTest.MergeKLists(arr);

        }
    }

    public class MergeKSortedListsTest
    {
        public static ListNode MergeKLists(ListNode[] lists)
        {
            if (lists == null || lists.Length == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            MinHeap<ListNode> heap = new MinHeap<ListNode>(new ListNodeComparer());
            ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
            ListNode tail = dummy;
            foreach (ListNode node in lists)
            {
                if (node != null)
                {
                    heap.Add(node);
                }
            }

            while (heap.Count > 0)
            {
                tail.next = heap.ExtractDominating();
                tail = tail.next;
                if (tail.next != null)
                {
                    heap.Add(tail.next);
                }
            }

            return dummy.next;
        }

        public class ListNodeComparer : Comparer<ListNode>
        {
            public override int Compare(ListNode o1, ListNode o2)
            {
                if (o1.val < o2.val)
                    return -1;
                else if (o1.val == o2.val)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you do not need to review the MinHeap code!

```
 public abstract class Heap<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        //capacity of the Queue
        private const int InitialCapacity = 0;

        private int _capacity = InitialCapacity;

        //items in the queue
        private T[] _heap = new T[InitialCapacity];

        //last item in the queue
        private int _tail = 0;

        //when growing the queue you multiply by Growfactor
        private const int GrowFactor = 2;
        // if the min size is 0 you grow the queue size by at least Min grow
        private const int MinGrow = 1;

        //how to compare the keys
        protected Comparer<T> Comparer { get; private set; }

        //store how many Items are in the queue
        public int Count { get { return _tail; } }

        //shows the current capacity of the queue
        public int Capacity { get { return _capacity; } }

        //this function is used in BubbleUp and in GetDominating
        protected abstract bool Dominates(T x, T y);

        protected Heap() : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
        {
        }
        protected Heap(Comparer<T> comparer) : this(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), comparer)
        {
        }
        protected Heap(IEnumerable<T> collection) : this(collection, Comparer<T>.Default)
        {
        }

        protected Heap(IEnumerable<T> collection, Comparer<T> comparer)
        {
            if (collection == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
            }

            if (comparer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
            }

            Comparer = comparer;
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                if (Count > Capacity)
                {
                    Grow();
                }

                _heap[_tail++] = item;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Parent(_tail - 1); i++)
            {
                BubbleDown(i);
            }
        }


        public void Add(T item)
        {
            if (Count == Capacity)
            {
                Grow();
            }

            _heap[_tail++] = item;
            BubbleUp(_tail - 1);
        }


        //when adding a new item we bubble the item from tail-1 up to its'
        //correct position
        private void BubbleUp(int i)
        {
            if (i == 0 || Dominates(_heap[Parent(i)], _heap[i]))
            {
                return; //correct domination (or root)
            }

            Swap(i, Parent(i));
            BubbleUp(Parent(i));
        }

        // when adding new items into the queue from the CTOR
        // we bubble them down
        private void BubbleDown(int i)
        {
            int dominatingNode = Dominating(i);
            if (dominatingNode == i)
            {
                return;
            }
            Swap(i,dominatingNode);
            BubbleDown(dominatingNode);
        }

        public T GetMin()
        {
            if (Count == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Heap is empty");
            }
            return _heap[0];
        }

        private void Swap(int i, int j)
        {
            T tmp = _heap[i];
            _heap[i] = _heap[j];
            _heap[j] = tmp;
        }

        public static int Parent(int i)
        {
            return (i + 1) / 2 - 1;
        }

        private void Grow()
        {
            int newCapcity = _capacity * GrowFactor + MinGrow;
            var newHeap = new T[newCapcity];
            Array.Copy(_heap, newHeap, _capacity);
            _heap = newHeap;
            _capacity = newCapcity;
        }

        //return from 0 up to Count
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _heap.Take(Count).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }


        //when we bubble down, when building the queue from a list in the CTOR
        // we need to understand who is dominating i, and we swap them,
        // and call bubbleDown again
        private int Dominating(int i)
        {
            int dominatingNode = i;
            dominatingNode = GetDominating(YoungChild(i), dominatingNode);
            dominatingNode = GetDominating(OldChild(i), dominatingNode);
            return dominatingNode;
        }

        private int GetDominating(int newNode, int dominatingNode)
        {
            if (newNode < _tail && !Dominates(_heap[dominatingNode], _heap[newNode]))
            {
                return newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                return dominatingNode;
            }
        }

        private static int YoungChild(int i)
        {
            return 2 * (i + 1) - 1;
        }

        private static int OldChild(int i)
        {
            return YoungChild(i) + 1;
        }

        public T ExtractDominating()
        {
            if (Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Heap is empty");
            T ret = _heap[0];
            _tail--;
            Swap(_tail, 0);
            BubbleDown(0);
            return ret;
        }

    }

    public class MinHeap<T> : Heap<T>
    {
        public MinHeap()
            : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
        {
        }

        public MinHeap(Comparer<T> comparer)
            : base(comparer)
        {
        }

        public MinHeap(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
        {
        }

        public MinHeap(IEnumerable<T> collection, Comparer<T> comparer)
            : base(collection, comparer)
        {
        }

        protected override bool Dominates(T x, T y)
        {
            return Comparer.Compare(x, y) <= 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I don't like is, that you merge "in place" - that is: the input linked lists change as a side effect. I would expect them to be untouched by the method. Consider to make a new linked list as the result.

---

As a micro optimization you could probably spare a couple of ticks, if the input lists contain a lot of duplicate values, by iterate to the first node with a greater value in the second loop:

```
  while (heap.Count > 0)
  {
    ListNode node = heap.ExtractDominating();
    tail.next = node;

    while (node.next != null && node.val == node.next.val)
    {
      node = node.next;
    }

    if (node.next != null)
    {
      heap.Add(node.next);
    }
      tail = node;

  }
```